# postgres ERROR: column "id" does not exist?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have created a table in postgres using the StaticSentence below. The table reads is created from  another table products, and the data within is deleted because I just want the schema(I'm really new at this thing but I'm sure there's a better way to handle this).

```
public void syncProductsBefore() throws BasicException {
    new StaticSentence(s,"CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS_imports(ID) WITH OIDS  AS SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS ").exec();
    new StaticSentence(s, "DELETE FROM PRODUCTS_imports").exec();
}
```

then I try to write into this table using a PreparedSentence in the method below. An update command is run first to know whether to insert new data or update existing ones.

public void syncProduct(final ProductInfoExt prod) throws BasicException {

```
    Transaction t = new Transaction(s) {
        public Object transact() throws BasicException {
            /*Sync the Product in a transaction*/

            /* Try to update*/
            if (new PreparedSentence(
                    s,
                    "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET REFERENCE = ?, CODE = ?, NAME = ?, PRICEBUY = ?, PRICESELL = ?, CATEGORY = ?, TAXCAT = ?, IMAGE = ? WHERE ID = ?",
                    SerializerWriteParams.INSTANCE).exec(new DataParams() {
                public void writeValues() throws BasicException {
                    setString(1, prod.getReference());
                    setString(2, prod.getCode());
                    setString(3, prod.getName());
                    // setBoolean(x, p.isCom());
                    // setBoolean(x, p.isScale());
                    setDouble(4, prod.getPriceBuy());
                    setDouble(5, prod.getPriceSell());
                    setString(6, prod.getCategoryID());
                    setString(7, prod.getTaxCategoryID());
                    setBytes(8, ImageUtils.writeImage(prod.getImage()));
                    // setDouble(x, 0.0);
                    // setDouble(x, 0.0);
                    setString(9, prod.getID());
                }
            }) == 0) {


                /* leyonce */
                /**
                 * If not updated, try to insert insert into the import
                 * temporary table create temporary sorted copies of product
                 * catalog and products
                 */
                new PreparedSentence(
                        s,
                        "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS_imports(ID, REFERENCE, CODE, NAME, ISCOM, ISSCALE, PRICEBUY, PRICESELL, CATEGORY, TAXCAT, IMAGE, STOCKCOST, STOCKVOLUME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                        SerializerWriteParams.INSTANCE)
                        .exec(new DataParams() {                            
                            public void writeValues() throws BasicException{

                            /*leyonce --insert values into temporary import table*/ 
                                setString(1, prod.getID());
                                setString(2, prod.getReference());
                                setString(3, prod.getCode());
                                setString(4, prod.getName());
                                setBoolean(5, prod.isCom());
                                setBoolean(6, prod.isScale());
                                setDouble(7, prod.getPriceBuy());
                                setDouble(8, prod.getPriceSell());
                                setString(9, prod.getCategoryID());
                                setString(10, prod.getTaxCategoryID());
                                setBytes(11, ImageUtils.writeImage(prod
                                        .getImage()));
                                setDouble(12, 0.0);
                                setDouble(13, 0.0);
```

);
}

Now the update runs perfectly but when the compiler gets to the insert statement, it rolls back and returns an error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: column "id" does not exist
  Position: 84
```

I really don't get why.

Comment: What are `StaticSentence` and `PreparedSentence`? Are those custom wrappers around *JDBC* classes, i.e. `PreparedStatement`? Googling `PreparedSentence` turns up a few different custom classes derived from *JDBC* classes...

Comment: Show us the `create table` statement for the table `products`

Answer (score 0):

```
psql
\d PRODUCTS_imports
\d PRODUCTS
```

do they have the ID column?

If the original table (products) is missing the ID column that would explain the error.

Comment: the table PRODUCTS exists.

Comment: Does the column ID exist in the table PRODUCTS?  If it does, then I cannot explain the error message.

Comment: A similar question (at least the cause of the problem seems to be identical) was posted here: [#10015531](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015531)